# Can I implement facebook and twitter in openfeint?

Tags: facebook, twitter, sharekit, openfeint

I want to implement social networking such as facebook and twitter in my game. I already have tried sharekit for ios version of my game. But am not that much satisfied with sharekit performance for following reasons:

1. Facebook permission page open in safari by sharekit did not close automatically.
2. The cancel button is not working(I have tried all solution given on different websites). this make me unable to return to my game when i sign-in into twitter.

Since my game is going to be released on many platform, such as android and wp7, I have to use openfeint anyway. So please give me advice if you can suggest me how to fix the above problem and how can I implement facebook and twitter using openfeint?

Answer (score 0):

@someone_smiley, if you can live with just iOS & Android, you can try Socialize: http://www.GetSocialize.com.  Open-source SDKs + a focus on driving app discovery via user's social actions (i.e., "put your users to work to drive installs of your app")

Full disclosure: I'm the CEO, so let me know about any rants or raves if you give it a try.